# Recompile the java files which is decompiled by JD-GUI from a jar

Tags: java, jar, compilation, recompile, jd-gui

I have a MyFile.jar file. I use JD-GUI to decompile it and used its "Save All Sources" options to save the files to a .zip file. Now extracted the .zip file and edited a .java file.

the folder structure after extracting .zip file is like this

```
                       _____ META-INF(folder)
source(folder) -------|     
                      ------com(folder)-->example--->App---> all .java files
```

now how do i recompile it back to .jar file ??

Comment: And which answers have you found?

Comment: Compile it with `javac` and use `jar` to make a jar from the compiled class.

Comment: i tried to compile the .java filed using `javac` but i get errors in various .java files -- error: package android.os does not exist, error: cannot file symbol .etc . how do i resolve these errors.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your question, you have decompiled the class files to java files and have done necessary modifications.

Hope you have imported that as a project in eclipse. Export the same as jar. point to be noted is that you should know the dependencies for building the project

Comment: how do i find out the dependencies ??

Comment: Easy approach - Try to import the extracted source code. The compilation errors will leads you to find out the dependencies

Comment: i tried to import project into eclipse(juno-downloaded from the android developers website) by browsing to the source folder but eclipse shows no projects found to import.

Comment: As it is a jar, you cannot import the project. Better to create a project(I prefer maven) and copy the source. Sorry for using the word 'import'. That made the confusion.

Comment: often sources decompiled with JD have several errors in it. You should in any case fix your classes, in eclipse for exampe, As said by dasrohith, create a project in eclipse and put your classes there